# mysqldump-like process for Amazon Aurora MySQL?

Tags: mysqldump, aws-aurora

I believe that mysqldump does not work with Amazon Aurora MySQL. This is a bit of a problem for us as we used use that tool - before moving to Amazon hosting - to extract information across tables to produce a full dump of the data for a single customer.

Are there any tools that work with Aurora MySQL that let you do a select-based data dump?

Comment: Can I ask why you believe that mysqldump does not work with Amazon Aurora MySQL? (e.g. Is there an article/document you can cite?)